# OpenTK: System.ExecutionEngineException at GLFW.PollEvents()

Tags: c#, .net-core, opentk

I am trying to create a 2D game using C# and OpenTK. For the engine part, I am roughly following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLtrSb4XxIVbp8AKuEAlwNXDxr99e3woGE). Everything worked as it should until I tried to add texture batching. At that point I got the first ExecutionEngineException (EEE). Now even if I use the code from before the changes, I get an EEE. It is only resolved if:

- I only use one RenderBatch
- I don't pass the view and projection matrices and additional vertex attributes to the shader

As soon as I either pass the matrices or additional vertex attributes to the shader, an EEE is thrown.

I also got a System.AccessViolationException sometimes, but can't find a controlled environment to consistently recreate it.

The source code can be found [here](https://github.com/mosel00/SurvivalGame). The main problem file is [RenderBatch.cs](https://github.com/mosel00/SurvivalGame/blob/master/SurvivalGame/Rendering/RenderBatch.cs) and the error occurs in [Window.cs](https://github.com/mosel00/SurvivalGame/blob/master/SurvivalGame/Window.cs) at line  95.
The program is currently in a state in which it doesn't crash.

The amount of RenderBatches can be controlled in [Renderer.cs](https://github.com/mosel00/SurvivalGame/blob/master/SurvivalGame/Rendering/Renderer.cs) at line six with the `maxBatchSize` constant and in [GameScene.cs](https://github.com/mosel00/SurvivalGame/blob/master/SurvivalGame/Scenes/GameScene.cs) at the lines 21 and 22 (the amount of iterations). A new RenderBatch is created when all existing ones are full. Currently 10000 GameObjects are created. The `maxBatchSize` controls how many GameObjects fit into one RenderBatch.

Passing the view and projection matrix to the shader is achieved by uncommenting lines 87 and 88 in [RenderBatch.cs](https://github.com/mosel00/SurvivalGame/blob/master/SurvivalGame/Rendering/RenderBatch.cs) and passing more vertex attributes to the shader is achieved by integrating the commented in line 21 and uncommenting lines 72 to 75 and 158 to 161 also in [RenderBatch.cs](https://github.com/mosel00/SurvivalGame/blob/master/SurvivalGame/Rendering/RenderBatch.cs).

For the environment I am using:

- Visual Studio Community 2019 16.7.5
- C# 8.0 with .NET Core 3.1
- OpenTK 4.0.0
- System.Drawing.Common 4.7.0
- .NET SDK 5.0.100-rc.1.20452.10 but never uninstalled the latest stable version
- Windows 10 Pro

Comment: In my experience, access violations happened to me in OpenTK when something wasn't initialized correctly.

Comment: While searching for an initialization error, I managed to get an error log from GLFW with which I could solve the issue (as written in my answer). Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now solved the issue.

After I set the error callback for GLFW after GLFW.Init instead of before, I got an error log from GLFW. This error log corresponded to the one found [here](https://github.com/opentk/opentk/issues/1073). Creating private fields for every callback even if it was a static method solved the issue for me.